# RPCS on Server disappear after idle time of 15-20min

Tags: php, symfony, websocket, rpc, thruway

I am really sorry for my Poor English.
I have created simple websocket game with voryx/ThruwayBundle for Symfony. Game uses RPCS registered on Server. Everything works fine but when I leave for about 20 mins RPCS are no longer available. And I have to restart websocket server to make them avaiable again.

I tried to register my rpcs as workers and I can see them running but they are still unavailable
[websocket server process status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GryUK.jpg)

The annotation I use to register RPC is

```
/**
 * @Register("games.snake.newplayer",serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true, worker="add-snake")
 */
```

I run server with command

```
nohup php app/console thruway:process start &
```

You can see it on http://amusement.cloudapp.net/

I am using **Ubuntu 15.10** server created in Microsoft azure if it's any help

I don't know what I can do to make those RPC available anytime without restarting websocket server. Should I make some cron action to reset websocket server if they're stopped responding and how can I do it.

**Edit#1**

RPCS work great on my local machine **Ubuntu 14.04**

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you run the server locally?

Comment: Yes and it appears that RPCS work great. Where can be culprit of this issue?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  I'm not that familiar with Azure.   I'm wondering if the connection is getting shut down after a while. Can you try setting up a remote client that "pings" the server every minute?

Comment: For now it's not possible. I cant ping that server. But even if i have opened ssh connection and start server without nohup rpcs disappear after a while. I created rpc to broadcast activity every 5seconds and this rpc stays accessible. For the rest that I don't use i get wamp error no procedure. But they were just after starting websocket serwer

Comment: Rpc for activity stays accessible until i stop using it. Then I get wamp error as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent disapeearing of rpcs I created symfony console command to ping them with some test data. Next I registered this command as cron job to be executed every minute.

I could't find the source of problem however it's easy way to avoid it.